# Root partition out of space side-effects

Tags: linux, partition

What are the side effects of the root (/) mount running out of space? If I remember correctly, users can no longer login. Are the effects flavor dependent?

Comment: It will be very slow and unstable and crashing. Put a file in each partition at least ~100MB and delete in case of emergency.

Answer (score 2):

If your root partition runs out of space you can expect a system downtime. You'll probably can SSH to it, but it would stop storing logs or even crash.

That's why best practices say to split your disk into a few partitions.
Splitting it into /, /tmp, and /home is quite a standard, but, besides that, you're supposed to create an additional partition for your services data.

i.e. If you're installing a database server, create a /var/db or /data partition
If you're installing a proxy server, create a /cache partition
I also like to create a /var partition in a way that logs wouldn't fill out root partition as well.

This way, if your system runs out of space because your service just fills it out, it would be limited to the partition its storing data, and your server would keep up and running. Although it would still lead to a service outage, your server tends to keep being accessible and logging data.